# Debugging Related : Why does this PHP code not working with desired behavior?

Tags: php

I was trying to understand use of Aliasing/Importing in php namespaces from  [php.net/manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) sample example.
I slightly modified the sample example to explore all the features of php namespace  Aliasing/Importing in a single code file.
I also added multiple namespaces in the same file to observe all the features.
Here is the php source code:

```
<?php
namespace foo{
echo "1-Inside namespace foo \n";
use My\Full\Classname as Another;
use ArrayObject; // importing a global class
echo "2-After using  ArrayObject line: ".__LINE__."\n"; 
    class Another {
  public function cname() {
        echo "line".__LINE__."Method".__METHOD__."\n";       
   }
   static function  method(){echo "line".__LINE__."Method: ".__METHOD__."\n";}
} 
//This line below is Not working.
$obj1 = new namespace\Another; // instantiates object of foo\Another
echo "3-After namespace\Another object line: ".__LINE__."\n";
//This line below is Not working.
echo "4-".$obj1->method()."\n";
//This line below is Not working.
$obj2 = new Another; // instantiates object of class My\Full\Classname
echo "5-After Another object line: ".__LINE__."\n";
//This line below is Not working.
echo "6-".$obj2->method()."\n";
echo "7-After Another object line: ".__LINE__."\n";
//This line below is Not working.
$a = new ArrayObject(array(1)); // instantiates object of ArrayObject
echo "8-After ArrayObject line: ".__LINE__."\n";
}

namespace My\Full{

class Classname{
    public function cname() {
        echo "line".__LINE__."Method".__METHOD__."\n";       
   }
   static function  method(){echo "line".__LINE__."Method: ".__METHOD__."\n";} } }    
?>
```

I expected & wanted these desired behavior/output to be printed given below:

```
1-Inside namespace foo 
2-After using ArrayObject line: x
3-After namespace\Another object line: x
4-line: x Method: foo\Another:method()
5-After Another object line: x
6-line: x Method: My\Full\Classname:method()
7-After Another object line: x
8-After ArrayObject line: x
```

But Instead of desired output, I got only few outputs with errors given below:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class foo\Another because the name is already in use in /home/himadree/ php workspace/ZCE/TOPIC1:BASICS/Namespaces/Using-namespaces-Aliasing-Importing.php on line 8
```

So, it looks like **there might be any identical naming conflicts** with the **class name Another**
Moreover i noticed that class 'Another' has 2 versions: foo\Another & My\Full\Classname as Another.After some useful comments i added extra class'Another'within namespace foo.But still its not working.Is this any the only error! i don't know.
Therefore in order to get my desired behavior/output,  what changes are needed in this code? I used eclipse php pdt tools, php version 5.5.
Since it is debug issue, so let me know if more specific information required.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem is that **there is no class `foo/Another` defined.** You're missing this within `namespace foo`:

```
class Another {}
```

Without it or something like it, `foo\Another` does not exist and attempting to instantiate it, as you are, will lead to a fatal error, as it does.

> Moreover i noticed that class 'Another' has 2 versions: foo\Another & My\Full\Classname as Another.

That's the point this code is trying to demonstrate. Just `Another` would be ambiguous, since it could refer to the aliased `as Another` or to `foo\Another`. Hence why `namespace\Another` is used to explicitly refer to `foo\Another`. As opposed to the `new Another`, which refers to the aliased `as Another`.

Comment: Thanks for useful comments .However, I re-edited the code and still got error.I think  there might be any identical naming conflicts with the class name Another.How can i resolve this problem keeping  identical name intact.although i am not sure is this the only error or not!

Comment: PHP seems to have conflicting implementations there. Some versions require you to declare the class in its own `namespace foo {}` block, others require it *before* the `use`, yet others don't seem to support it at all. It will probably work better if you autoload the class from a file as needed.